# Distributed Tensorflow - pass graph to other workers

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to achieve something like this:
Having one main script, where I setup what model configurations ( hyperparameters, hidden layers count etc ) I want to train and other scripts just training the defined graph/model with their batch of data, so I create a graph on master worker and then pass it to other workers without creating a graph on them. The configuration of the neural network ( amount of steps, learning rate, hidden layers, neurons in hidden layers ) should be known only in main script.

Something like:

```
main.py:  # should be run on master worker
  learning_rates = [ 0.1, 0.5 ]
  hidden_layers = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  for lr in learning_rates:
     for hl in hidden_layers:
        nn_train(lr, hl, x_train, y_train, cluster, job_name, task_index)
```

Whereas nn_train should be a neural network model script written with help of TensorFlow and support data parallelism training.
Other workers should have something like:

```
main_slave.py:
    nn_train(None, None, x_another_train, y_another_train, cluster, job_name, task_index)
```

The script might look something like:

```
nn_train.py:
    # Create and start a server for the local task.
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name=job_name, task_index=task_index)

    if job_name == "ps":
       server.join()
       return

   if job_name != "worker":
       raise 'Unknown job name: ' + job_name

   if lr and hl: # if they are defined, it's master worker, build the graph
       # Assigns ops to the local worker by default.
       with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(...)):
           train_op = ... # build whole model, ie graph
    else:
        train_op = ... # **somehow get the graph, how?**

    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,..) as sess:
       while not mon_sess.should_stop():
       # Run a training step asynchronously.
       # perform *synchronous* training.
       # sess.run handles AbortedError in case of preempted PS.
       sess.run(train_op)
```

So if nn_train is launched on master worker, then it builds a graph there according to the given parameters. If nn_train is launched on other workers, they just somehow get already defined graph and train it. I assume that each machine would have it's own dataset which will be passed in nn_train.

I hope I conveyed my problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.